# How to select dates with the same weekday one month apart (once a month) for a given year in SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, datetime

While making a simple event calendar I got stuck with this one query.
What I need is to schedule events that occour once a month, but at the same weekday and the same hour. I'm using SQLite and my idea was to register one given Datetime (YYYY-mm-dd HH:00:00) with a month repetition flag and, when retrieving the results, it would need to return the same weekday but once per month for a whole year. So, for this I would only need to have one record.

I have this query so far for normal, daily or weekly events:

```
    SELECT
            id,
            strftime("%H", time) AS hour,
            strftime("%d", time) AS day,
            strftime("%w", time) AS weekday,
            strftime("%m", time) AS month,
            strftime("%Y", time) AS year,
            name,
            event,
            repeat
    FROM event
    WHERE (year LIKE :year)
            AND
           (
             (day LIKE :day AND
             month LIKE :month AND
             repeat = 0)
              OR
             (repeat = 1)
              OR
             (weekday LIKE :weekday AND repeat = 2)
            );
```

I would be grateful for any help.

**EDIT:**
Solved by checking the month day number difference like so:

```
    SELECT
            id,
            strftime("%H", time) AS hour,
            strftime("%d", time) AS day,
            strftime("%w", time) AS weekday,
            strftime("%m", time) AS month,
            strftime("%Y", time) AS year,
            name,
            event,
            repeat
    FROM event
    WHERE (year LIKE :year)
            AND
           (
             (day LIKE :day AND
             month LIKE :month AND
              repeat = 0)
              OR
             (repeat = 1)
              OR
             (weekday LIKE :weekday AND 
              repeat = 2)
              OR
             (:day_int <= CAST(day AS INTEGER)+3 AND 
              :day_int >= CAST(day AS INTEGER)-3 AND 
              weekday LIKE :weekday AND 
              repeat = 3)
            );
```

Comment: @Ryan Vincent Once a month, any given weekday. Like a game scheduled for a tuesday once a month. I tried for a 4 week difference but ended up to check on the day difference.